# How to register a named type mapping to resolve to the unnamed type mapping

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am using entity framework with the unit of work design pattern, my class structure is as follows:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Save();
}

public class MyContext : ObjectContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public void Save()
    {
        SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I then register the MyContext type mapping as:

```
IUnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer()
    .RegisterType<MyContext>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

I know if I did the following:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, MyContext>();
IUnitOfWork unitOfWork1 = unityContainer.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
IUnitOfWork unitOfWork2 = unityContainer.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
```

Then `unitOfWork1` would be the same `MyContext` instance as `unitOfWork2`, as `IUnitOfWork` maps to `MyContext`, which is a container controlled instance.

However, if instead I do this:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, MyContext>("MyUnitOfWork");
IUnitOfWork unitOfWork1 = unityContainer.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>("MyUnitOfWork");
IUnitOfWork unitOfWork2 = unityContainer.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>("MyUnitOfWork");
```

Then `unitOfWork1` and `unitOfWork2` resolve to two different instances of `MyContext`, which doesn't make any sense to me, as they both map to MyContext, which is still a container controlled instance. It appears that when the mappings are named, they don't resolve the second type parameter in the same way.

The reason I require named type mappings is because I have multiple different `ObjectContext`s all of which implement `IUnitOfWork`, so it would be wrong to define a global `IUnitOfWork` type mapping.

My question is simply, how can I use named type mappings but still retain the functionality of the first implementation.

N.B. I am actually using a `PerResolveLifetimeManager` in my real implementation, however `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` highlights the point in less code.

**Edit**
As per my conversation with Daniel Hilgarth.

I fixed my problem by changing the registration of the class with a dependency property of `IUnitOfWork`.

Previously it was along the lines of:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<Service>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IUnitOfWork>("MyUnitOfWork")));
```

However, instead of resolving a named `IUnitOfWork`, I took a different approach and instead resolved the implementation directly:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<Service>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<MyContext>()));
```

Thank you Daniel and TheCodeKing for explaining the purpose of named registrations :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass the lifetime manager:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, MyContext>(
    "MyUnitOfWork", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Reason:
You registered the **unnamed** instance of `MyContext` as a container controlled instance, not the **named** one.

Comment: The problem with this approach is, if a class constructor has a dependency upon `MyContext`, it will get one instance, whereas if another class has a dependency upon `IUnitOfWork`, it will get a different instance of `MyContext`, assuming the class which has a dependency upon `IUnitOfWork` has an `InjectionConstructor` specifying `new ResolvedParameter<IUnitOfWork>("MyUnitOfWork")`.

Comment: Why are you using a named registration in the first place if you don't want two separate instances? The whole reason for named registrations is to provide different instances in different contexts.

Comment: If I have several classes which have a dependency upon an `IUnitOfWork`, in some situations I may wish this `IUnitOfWork` to be a `MyContext`, in other situations I may wish for it to be another implementation, hence I was using named registration to differentiate which implementation of `IUnitOfWork` to resolve to. The example I provided is a bit contrived, as per my note I am actually using a `PerResolveLifetimeManager`, so I would like different instances and implementations of `IUnitOfWork` for different resolves.

Comment: I understand the reason you give though, I am thinking that this might be the wrong thing to be registering a class with a dependency on `IUnitOfWork`: `unityContainer.RegisterType<Service>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IUnitOfWork>("MyUnitOfWork")))`.

Comment: If you check my original question, I have found a solution to the problem, I would have preferred to abstract away the registered implementation of `IUnitOfWork` to one place, however I believe it will suffice. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` enforces a singleton so you always get the same instance. To use named instances which resolve a singleton, you need.

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, MyContext>
                     ("MyUnitOfWork", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
IUnitOfWork unitOfWork1 = unityContainer.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>("MyUnitOfWork");
IUnitOfWork unitOfWork2 = unityContainer.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>("MyUnitOfWork");
```

Comment: If you see my response to Daniel Hilgarth, you will see why I believe this approach is not desirable either.

Comment: Sorry it's unclear to me what the question is. Use `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` if you want a singleton, don't if you don't. Use named instances to distinguish whether you want a new instance or an existing one. You can always use dependency overrides at resolve time. Maybe simplify the question into what you actually want to do?

Comment: Contrary to my contrived example, I am not using `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`, I merely used that to give a code sample. In my implementation I am using `PerResolveLifetimeManager`. If I have a class, which has two dependencies, each of which depend on `IUnitOfWork`, I would like to resolve these to the same instance of `MyContext`. I was doing this by using an `InjectionConstructor` and `new ResolvedParameter<IUnitOfWork>("MyUnitOfWork")`

Comment: If you check my original question, I have found a solution to the problem, I would have preferred to abstract away the registered implementation of `IUnitOfWork` to one place, however I believe it will suffice. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad you got there :)

Comment: Ok, I will bear that in mind for any future questions/answers :)